# Effects of dispersed nitrous oxide on the body

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, chemical-biology

I'm not sure if this question would be more appropriate in Biology SE, but I wanted to know if the euphoric effects of $\ce{N2O}$ are limited to when it is concentrated in the gaseous phase, or whether it can also affect individuals in cases where it may be mixed with other compounds as a sol (in essence, as the propellant in the whipped cream of ice-cream).

Maybe that might explain how ice cream is associated with happiness (in most cases and in a majority of people), the same way $\ce{N2O}$ is associated with euphoria. (The focus here being $\ce{N2O}$, not ice-cream-related dopamine reception in the brain.)

Researched a but but unable to find anything relevant.

Comment: Why are you looking for an additional theory as to why people like ice cream? Dopamine release due to sugar or fats triggering the pleasure system is more than enough to explain why people enjoy whipped cream and ice cream. Occam's Razor answers your question with a: *"No, that will not explain anything, it is well enough explained already".*

Comment: @Stian Yttervik I'm not looking for a theory, just for a possible answer since I find it interesting and I learn better by connecting new things to things I already know. I'm more interested in learning about N2O, not about why people like ice-cream. I've edited my post to make that more clear, thanks.

Comment: What matters is N2O concentration in blood as consequence of N2O exposure. Amount of N2O in the consumed cream is small, and eventual exposure to it distributed across long time. So my guess is the effect is negligible.